# Perfect forwarding to multiple constructors

Tags: c++11, constructor, perfect-forwarding

I'm really happy with the perfect forwarding in C++11 and want to do something more complicated. It's somewhat a classic case. I have a template axis-aligned box class. The template argument is a vector class. So I have a classic constructor, that takes 2 vectors:

```
template <class T> struct base_vec2 {
    typedef T scalar_type;
    base_vec2 (T a, T b); // counsruct for two scalar calues
};
template <class T> struct base_vec3 {
    typedef T scalar_type;
    base_vec2 (T a, T b, T c); // counsruct for three scalar calues
};
template <class T> struct base_box {
    typedef typename T::scalar_type scalar_type;
    T lower, upper; //<! upper and lower point
    base_box<T> (const T& min, const T& max);
};
base_box<base_vec3<float>> box;
```

Naturally, one may want to implement a constructor which takes n scalar values and pass them to the lower and upper constructors. This is what I came up with:

```
template <class T> struct base_box {
    .....
    template <typename... Ts> base_box<T> (scalar_type s1, scalar_type s2, scalar_type s3, scalar_type s4, Ts&&... ts) {
        base_box_construct<T, scalar_type, (4 + sizeof...(ts))/2> _(lower, upper, s1, s2, s3, s4, std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    }
};

base_box<base_vec2<float>> box(1, 2, 3, 4);
base_box<base_vec3<float>> box(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

base_box_construct do the actual magic:

```
template <class T, class A>
struct base_box_construct<T, A, 2> {
   template <typename... Ts>
   base_box_construct(T& lower, T& upper, A s1, A s2, A s3, A s4, Ts&&... ts)
   {
      lower = T(a1, a2);
      upper = T(a3, a4);
   }
};

template <class T, class A>
struct base_box_construct<T, A, 3> {
   template <typename... Ts>
   base_box_construct(T& lower, T& upper, A s1, A s2, A s3, A s4, Ts&&... ts)
   {
      lower = T(s1, s2, s3);
      upper = T(s4, std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
   }
};

template <class T, class A>
struct base_box_construct<T, A, 4> {
   template <typename... Ts>
   base_box_construct(T& lower, T& upper, A s1, A s2, A s3, A s4, Ts&&... ts)
   {
      lower = T(s1, s2, s3, s4);
      upper = T(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
   }
};
```

It's a bit tricky, since it works only with 2, 3 and 4 arguments per vector which is just what I need. But I was wondering if there is better way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use uniform initialization, no further changes required:

```
base_box<base_vec3<float>> box { { 1,2,3 }, { 4,5,6 } };
```

The standard does this in similar ways using `std::piece_wise_construct_t`

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ae358354d96a645)</kbd>**

```
template <class T> struct base_vec2 {
    typedef T scalar_type;
    T a, b;
    base_vec2 (T a, T b) : a(a), b(b) {} // construct for two scalar calues
};
template <class T> struct base_vec3 {
    typedef T scalar_type;
    T a, b, c;
    base_vec3 (T a, T b, T c) : a(a), b(b), c(c) {} // construct for three scalar calues
};
template <class T> struct base_box {
    typedef typename T::scalar_type scalar_type;
    T lower, upper; //<! upper and lower point
    base_box<T> (const T& min, const T& max)
        : lower(min), upper(max)
    { }
};

int main() {
    base_box<base_vec3<float>> box { { 1,2,3 }, { 4,5,6 } };
}
```